# Преобразование переменной типа String в переменную типа int

Tags: java, строки, типизация

Почему, чтобы присвоить переменную типа `String` переменной типа `int`, нужно `String` преобразовать в `int`? У `String` больше диапазон допустимых значений, чем у `int`? Я понимаю, что `int` - это целочисленный тип данных, и что я не смогу слово "Привет" присвоить переменной `int`. Но тут же, по сути, я хочу целое число присвоить.

```
String stringGuess = "2";
int intGuess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир [статической типизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), в котором каждая переменная имеет конкретный тип, известный на этапе компиляции, и компилятор не позволяет присвоить ей значения другого типа.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а у String есть определенный диапазон значений, как у примитивов ? К примеру явные и неявные преобразования. Или со String все работает по другому ?

Comment: @Влад String это не число, посему ограничения для String память устройства. Все работает иначе, да. Советую изучить примитивы и строки.

Comment: Код в вопросе размещайте форматированным текстом, а не скриншотами, пожалуйста.

Comment: String не может быть int примерно по той же причине, почему написанное ручкой на туалетной бумажке "100 баксов" не могут быть реальными сотней долларов. Ведь вас не удивляет, что никто не принимает к оплате надпись на бумажке, а написанные символами цифры вы готовы принять за реальное число. String это текстовый тип и туда вы можете присвоить не число 2, а символ "2"

Answer (score 2):

Всё очень просто, так как `int` это примитивный тип, а вот `String` это по сути класс обертка над массивом `char`.

Если посмотреть исходный код класса `String` все станет понятнее.

```
public final class String ... {
    //Это и есть наш массив, в котором храниться последовательность строк
    private final char[] value;
}
```

Конечно можно сказать что один `char` без проблем войдет в один `int`, но для этого нам необходимо выбрать какой именно символ из массива мы хотим складировать в нашем примитиве `int`. К тому же когда ты присваиваешь строку `"2"` в `int` непонятно что ты хочешь. Получить ее номер в таблице `Unicod`, распарсить её значение, а может вообще получить её длину. Поэтому и нельзя сделать автоматический "анбоксинг" как в случае с `int` и `Integer`. Нет однозначности, а компилятор не может прочитать твои мысли.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Java это [статически типизированный язык](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). 
У этого есть свои преимущества:

> - Статическая типизация даёт самый простой машинный код. Поэтому она удобна для языков, дающих исполняемые файлы ОС или JIT-компилируемые промежуточные коды.
> - Многие ошибки исключаются уже на стадии компиляции.
> - Поэтому статическая типизация хороша для написания сложного, но быстрого кода.
> - В интегрированной среде разработки осуществимо более релевантное автодополнение, особенно если типизация — сильная статическая: множество вариантов можно отбросить как не подходящие по типу.

Это все из-за выделения памяти под ваши переменные(и не только).

> Каждая переменная в Java имеет конкретный тип, который определяет размер и размещение её в памяти; диапазон значений, которые могут храниться в памяти; и набор операций, которые могут быть применены к переменной.

В Java есть [примитивные типы](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)(`int`, `byte`, `long`, и т.п.), а есть и [ссылочные](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) - например, `String`. И если при операциях с примитивными типами вы можете их приводить неявно, (`long x = int y`), но они все равно приводятся, то при операциях с примитивными и ссылочными типами(`int i = String s`) вам придется приводить их явно(например, [парсить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787735/what-is-parse-parsing)).

Еще статьи на эту тему: [про типы](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/types.php), [про статическую/динамическую типизацию](https://habr.com/post/308484/).